# Drupal l function does not work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

I am trying to highlight nids of pages when I am using $nid = $node->nid they stop working of function l in drupal 7 but our nids is highlighted 
here is my code

```
$ch1=db_query("SELECT th.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON th.tid=td.tid
  INNER JOIN field_data_field_books book ON book.field_books_tid = th.tid
  WHERE td.vid = '6' AND th.parent = $ch AND book.entity_id = $nid
  ")->FetchField();

$chap1=taxonomy_get_children($ch1);
echo "<ul>";
foreach($chap1 as $ca1){
  $pnid = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM node n 
  INNER JOIN field_data_field_books book ON book.entity_id = n.nid
  WHERE  book.field_books_tid = $ca1->tid AND n.nid = $nid " )->FetchField();
  if($nid == $pnid){
    print "<li class='b'><b>".$ca1->name."</b></li>";
  } else {
    $link = l($ca1->name, 'node/' . $pnid);
  print "<li class='a'>". $link."</li>";
  }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: are you sure that $pnid is the correct nid, try to print it and debug.

Comment: yes it is correct nid

Answer (score 0):

Try url function as below:

```
$link = url('node/' . $pnid);
print "<li class='a'><a href='". $link."'> ".$ca1->name." </a></li>";
```

Comment: its not working it is not connect to its node they show "en/node" next path are not showing like "en/content/how to work sience"